Using flutter with VS Code and while running Error: Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run `flutter doctor` for more details
I am trying to run my flutter on windows and I am running on VS code and the below error is coming

Error: Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run 'flutter doctor' for more details.

How to resolve this?
I tried doing flutter doctor but there seems to be an error with visual studio installation. but in the video from which I am learning clearly stated that there is no need of Visual Studio and that we can use VS Code.

If you aren't intended to build windows app skip this for now, or else you can follow this
